# The specified authorization code has already been redeemed after Enable Redis for abp

Tags: redis, abp

I follow this document to enable redis
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Redis-Cache?&_ga=2.84794841.1118577770.1688628013-487746807.1664031769#configuration

But after that I get error while logging in

The specified authorization code has already been redeemed
OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated.

It seems openiddict cannot understand redis

I tried to connect to Redis server by .net client, and success. So no problem with Redis server connection

Comment: I found the problem, it is because my react client has timeout at 3500ms